# Chrome Web Store - i published extension in google chrome web store but showing incompatible?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-web-store

Same extension when i upload to Google chrome web store it saying not compatible.

[image]

But using Chromium or Google chrome when i load the same extension manually  from local directory it works. Extension was supposed to work for Windows and OSX but its saying Chromium OS only

how do i tell its not only for Chromium OS?

```
{ 
  "name" : “DEBUG - USB”,
  "version" : "1.0.1",
  "description" : "USB 2.0 connect”,
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      “*://*.site.com/*”,
    ]
  }, 
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
    }
  },   
  "permissions" : [ 
    "serial",
    “*://*.site.com/*”,
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: You're using the word 'extension', but this manifest is for an app.

Comment: True, its an APP to connect RS232.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i tell its not only for Chromium OS?

You don't. This is a manifest for a Chrome App - and [as per deprecation policy](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html) new Apps are only useable on Chrome OS, the only officially supported platform.

> **Starting in late 2016, newly-published Chrome apps will only be available to users on Chrome OS.** Existing Chrome apps will remain accessible on all platforms, and developers can continue to update them.
>   In the second half of 2017, the Chrome Web Store will no longer show Chrome apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux, but will continue to surface extensions and themes. In early 2018, users on these platforms will no longer be able to load Chrome apps.

Since you're using `serial` permission, and there is no equivalent extension/web API, you can't switch to an extension, so basically no, you can't distribute using CWS.

Note that you probably can replicate the functionality in an extension with [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), but that will complicate deployment (CWS won't host your native host component).

Comment: Thank you. Second problem is if i load the app manually in Google chrome, which works but Then Google chrome always shows a popup (on KIOSK 
 mode application): https://i.stack.imgur.com/861MU.png

Comment: If I remember correctly, there are no restrictions on distribution of apps; you could _pack_ it locally in a CRX and load that instead of unpacked version. But take notice that in 2018, Apps will stop working completely on Win/macOS.

Comment: OK - thank you very clear now (Google chrome wont be trusted for this task, i have to do it some other native way instead of depending on official Google chrome for long term stable project that i am working on now)

Comment: You could try the Google-recommended migration path - Electron / NW.js runtime. Migration from a Chrome app should be pretty straightforward. Whether they have the `serial`-equivalent capability is another matter.. This looks promising: https://github.com/johnny-five-io/electron-serialport